Создание номенклатуры 1С
Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой создания номенклатуры в 1С, используя OData и Python. Вот мой код:
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

post_url = 'http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0'

data_to_post = {
    "Description": "Товар на продажу",
    "Code": "1234554321"
}

ns = {
    'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
    'm': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata',
    'd': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices'
}

root = ET.Element(ET.QName(ns['atom'], 'entry'))
content = ET.SubElement(root, ET.QName(ns['atom'], 'content'), type="application/xml")
properties = ET.SubElement(content, ET.QName(ns['m'], 'properties'))

for key, value in data_to_post.items():
    prop = ET.SubElement(properties, ET.QName(ns['d'], key))
    prop.text = value

xml_data = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

response = requests.post(post_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username='odata.user', password=''), data=xml_data, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Data successfully posted.")
    print("Response:", response.text)
else:
    print(f"Failed to post data: {response.status_code}")
    print("Response content:", response.text)

В итоге выдает такую ошибку
Failed to post data: 500
Response content: <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1</m:code>
    <m:message>Ошибка при выполнении обработчика - 'ПередЗаписью'</m:message>
</m:error>

Сколько не гуглил, так и не нашел людей, которые сталкивались с этим. Подскажите пожалуйста как эту проблему решить, может добавить какой-либо параметр или проще использовать уже готовую библиотеку

Ошибка 500 дает вам понять, что сервер не может обработать ваш запрос. Даже не так, ваш запрос вызывает ошибку на сервере. По 1С ничего не могу сказать, но я бы искал ответ в документации как отсылать запросы к вашему сервису, ссылаясь на сообщение об ошибке.

Проблема может быть в том, что у пользователя, под которым работает OData нет прав на внесение изменений, в настройках OData нет информации о правах, а в пользователях odata.user не отображается, можете подсказать как выдать ему эти права?

не смогу, поскольку я никогда не работал с 1С + смотрю, что OData для 1С несет какой то другой смысл, чем я себе это представляю. Подождите, может кто-то другой сможет вам помочь

@auem, это внутренняя ошибка 1С. Создание элемента справочника выполняется в транзакции, проходя через обработчики "ПередЗаписью", "ПриЗаписи", "ОбработкаПровекиЗаполнения" и т.п., в которых выполняется какой-либо код.

Разобрался, проблема была просто в правах пользователя, стандартный пользователь odata.user, которого предлагает создать система, умеет только читать данные. Для изменения нужно либо наделить правами этого (не пробовал), либо работать из под другого, который может делать те же самые действия в системе. В пользователях создал нового, название обязательно на английском, иначе система будет ругаться
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)

И под именем этого пользователя делаю запрос

ну это оочень странно, и не в вашей реализации, в принципе. Если не подходят права доступа, то по всем канонам необходимо вернуть 40x ошибку (например 403), но почему 500 - это загадка

Данные добавились успешно, но в самом 1С добавленные товары не отобразились, видимо из-за того, что не прописал данные для привязки к справочникам или что-то в этом роде
